# xcode obj ios ignoring file CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony, missing required architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm getting this error, anyone got any ideas?

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Project/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/Project/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony (3 slices)

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in User.o

Comment: Do you have multiple targets in your project? If yes, ensure you are linking the framework in all targets.

Comment: no only one target..

Comment: if the Telephony framework is not added shouldn't I get an error on: #import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>